# Embed an ES6 Arrow Function in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to embed an ES6 Arrow Function within a `JSON` object?

Example, would the following data format be considered "valid"?

```
{
     function:{() => {console.log("executed")}}
}
```

Comment: No, that's not valid JSON.

Comment: Did you test it? Testing will takes less time then writing a question ;)

Comment: Then, is it not valid to pass functions in within a JSON object?

Comment: @Fabio I did test it before I wrote the question and it failed, it is just an example, is there a way to format it such that it would be valid?

Comment: Per the specification, the JSON text format does not accept functions.  Now, a Javascript object can indeed have a property that is a function.  Since people regularly mix up those two separate things, I'm not sure what you meant, though you refer to JSON which is a text format and does not accept functions.  A Javascript object could have a function like this: `let obj = {somePropertyName: function() { console.log("hi")}}` that could then be called as `obj.somePropertyName()`.

Comment: FYI there's no such thing as a 'JSON object'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, there is no such thing as a JSON object.  JSON is a text format, not an object format.  There is JSON text and Javascript objects.  The two are completely different things.

Per the [JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), the JSON text format does not accept functions.  Values in a JSON formatted string are described in this spec in shorthand like this:

```
value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string
```

Those are the types that are allowed in JSON.

---

On the other hand, a Javascript object can indeed have a property that is a function. Since people regularly mix up those two separate things, I'm not sure what you meant, though you refer to JSON which is a text format and does not accept functions.

A Javascript object could have a function like this:

```
let obj = {
    somePropertyName: function() { console.log("hi")}
};
```

that could then be called as:

```
 obj.somePropertyName();
```

ES6 syntax also allows a few other ways to declare the function, but the idea is the same.  You end up with a named property on the object that points to a function.  Using an arrow function with ES6 syntax:

```
let obj = {
    somePropertyName: () => { console.log("hi")}
};
```

It is important to realize that when using an arrow function, the value of `this` when that function is called will NOT be set to the object itself since by definition, an arrow function uses the lexical form of `this`, and `this` is not set by how the method is called as it is with a normal function definition.